# Eliminar filas de JTable al presionar SUPR - Java

Tags: java, addkeylistener

Tengo un `JTable` en mi proyecto el cual contiene datos de clientes. Quisiera que al presionar la tecla **SUPR**, habiendo fila/s seleccionada/s, haga la misma función que el evento del `button_eliminar`.

El código de eliminar (sobre las fila/s seleccionada/s) funciona correctamente. ¿Cómo puedo hacer lo mismo presionando la tecla **SUPR**?

He pensado en llamar al evento `AddKeyListener` y con las fila/s seleccionada/s `tabla_clientes.getSelectedRows();` hacer el mismo borrado. En alguna parte del código, la siguiente función... ¿Cómo puedo relacionar para que al pulsar **SUPR** también borre las filas?

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE){
    //¿Debo poner el mismo código que en el button_eliminar?
    //¿O puedo llamar a la función aún siendo ActionListener?
}
```

Código del **button_eliminar**:

```
   private void button_eliminarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) tabla_clientes.getModel();
        
        int fila = tabla_clientes.getSelectedRow();
        int nFilasSelec = tabla_clientes.getSelectedRowCount(); 
        if (fila < 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe seleccionar al menos un cliente.");
            textfield_buscar.requestFocus();
        } else if (nFilasSelec == 1) {
            String dni = (String) modelo.getValueAt(fila, 0);
            String nombre = (String) modelo.getValueAt(fila, 1);
            int confirmado = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog
            (null, "¿Deseas eliminar al cliente "+nombre+" "+dni+"?", "Administrador", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            if(JOptionPane.OK_OPTION == confirmado){
                int[] filasselec  = tabla_clientes.getSelectedRows();
                for (int i=filasselec.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    //Obtener el "id" de la fila seleccionada, no del orden del for.
                    String dni_a_eliminar = (String) tabla_clientes.getValueAt(filasselec[i], 0);
                    Conexiones.eliminar_cliente(dni_a_eliminar);
                    modelo.removeRow(filasselec[i]);
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Borrado realizado con éxito.");
            }else{
                tabla_clientes.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            }
        } else if (nFilasSelec >= 2) {
            int confirmado = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Deseas eliminar estos "+nFilasSelec+" clientes?", "Administrador", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            if(JOptionPane.OK_OPTION == confirmado){
                int[] filasselec  = tabla_clientes.getSelectedRows();
                for (int i=filasselec.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    //Obtener el "id" de la fila seleccionada, no del orden del for.
                    String dni_a_eliminar = (String) tabla_clientes.getValueAt(filasselec[i], 0);
                    Conexiones.eliminar_cliente(dni_a_eliminar);
                    modelo.removeRow(filasselec[i]);
                } 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Borrado realizado con éxito.");
            }else{
                tabla_clientes.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que agregar el evento `KeyListener` a la tabla y hacer la validación, nada más.

Algo así (es para eliminar todo, pero espero te ayude, es similar):

```
private void tablaKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                  
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE) {

        for (int i = 0; i < tabla.getRowCount(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tabla.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                tabla.setValueAt("", i, j);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda realizar el evento sobre la tabla, pero... ¿se puede llamar al método button_eliminarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) dentro del evento TablaKeyReleased o debo escribir todo el código del borrado de filas de nuevo.

Comment: Si es posible, solo llama al metodo, usando boton.doClick()

Comment: Logrado. Gracias.